# CUDA 11.3 not being detected by PyTorch [Anaconda]

Tags: pytorch, anaconda

I am running Ubuntu `20.04` on `GTX 1050TI`. I have installed CUDA `11.3`.

`nvidia-smi` output:

```
Wed Apr  6 18:27:23 2022       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 465.19.01    Driver Version: 465.19.01    CUDA Version: 11.3     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA GeForce ...  Off  | 00000000:01:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| N/A   44C    P8    N/A /  N/A |     11MiB /  4040MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A      3060      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                  4MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      4270      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                  4MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

`nvcc --version` output:

```
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2021 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Sun_Mar_21_19:15:46_PDT_2021
Cuda compilation tools, release 11.3, V11.3.58
Build cuda_11.3.r11.3/compiler.29745058_0
```

Anaconda PyTorch isn't detecting CUDA:

```
> import torch
> torch.cuda.is_available()
> False
```

Any ideas how to solve the issue?

Comment: Did you install as instructed by [documentation](https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/): `conda install pytorch torchvision torchaudio cudatoolkit=11.3 -c pytorch`?

Comment: Yup! It turned out that conda installed the cpu build and not the CUDA build. The fix is to install with pip instead! Looks weird for me but that's the solution!

Answer (score 1):

The solution:

`Conda` in my case installed **cpu** build. You can easily identify your build type by running `torch.version.cuda` which should return a **string** in case you have the **CUDA** build. if you get **None** then you are running the **cpu** build and it will not detect **CUDA**

To fix that I installed torch using `pip` instead :

`pip3 install torch torchvision torchaudio --extra-index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu113`

Comment: Conda only installs a CPU build if you ask it to. If you ask it to install a GPU build, it will do so

Comment: what's the command for GPU specific build @talonmies?

Comment: https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/pytorch-gpu